# Easiest way to add a numeric value to a String name

Tags: java, android, string, loops

I have a string name called "name" that I am looking to convert to name1, name2, name3, name4

what would be the best way to go about doing this?  Is there a way to tie it into a loop?

```
public String name;
```

***Loop Start***

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      name = input.getText().toString();
      // Do something with value!
}
```

***Loop End***

Looking for each time it goes through the loop to become name1, name2, name3, name4..

is it possible to do something like

```
name(nameLoop) = input.getText().toString();
...
nameLoop++;
```

I hope this isnt too confusing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, write something like `String newName = name+nameLoop;`

or `String newName = "name"+nameLoop;` if you literally want them to be name1, name2 etc.